# How to write '?' symbol in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using htaccess. I try to pass a value in url like '/?'

like "domain.com/?detail.html"
I am retrieving the value in htaccess like

RewriteRule ^?(.*).html$ index.php?key=detail

But it returns only 'detail'. Symbol '?' not accepted. I need the the value '?detail.html'

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not understand how URLs are build. The ? has a special meaning in it. It separates URL and query string. You cannot capture or detect it in a rewriting rule since it is not part of the URL.

If that URL really is what you get as a request, then this would rewrite it as you want:

```
RewriteEngine in
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(\w+)\.html$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /index.php?key=%1 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).